# How to provide second level cache with redis in spring data jpa？

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How to provide second level cache  with redis in spring data jpa?

not only hibernate，I hope all jpa provider can use this cache.

somebody can help？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on a JPA implementation library used by an application with spring-data-jpa. I'll be speaking about 2 popular JPA implementations: Hibernate and Eclipselink.

Eclipselink is only able to use its own 2nd level cache provider and hence is not able to leverage Redis as a 2nd level cache.

Hibernate provides an ability to use 3rd party cache libraries as a 2nd level cache provider. Latest Hibernate 5.1 comes with built-in support for two caching libraries: Ehcache and Infinispan: [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/caching/Caching.html). There are proprietary and open source libraries supporting other caching providers including Redis: [GitHub: debop/hibernate-redis](https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis).